# Stripe API - get success url using paymentIntentID

Tags: stripe-payments

Through Stripe API - is there a way to retrieve the original `checkout_session` using `paymentIntentId` (e.g. pi_XYZABC2423) or `chargeId` (e.g. ch_3QOXYZABCD)?

I specifically need `success url` (or `cancel url`), which I believe are parts of the checkout session

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the List Checkout Sessions [API](https://stripe.com/docs/api/checkout/sessions/list) which comes with a `payment_intent` parameter to search through all Sessions and return the one associated with your PaymentIntent id `pi_123`. Then you can look at the results, which would return one Session if any matched.

Comment: This is it! Thank you so much @koopajah